# How to make a form with that picks questions and saves answers from/into database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a form that brings questions and answers from the database, i have several questions, but i want to answer one question on each page and then go to the next question. How can i make that possible? i need some tips.

My code for bringing the questions and answers looks like this:

```html
echo "<form method='post'>";
 $sql= "SELECT pid, qid, question_link FROM question  ORDER BY qid ASC LIMIT 1";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
 $pid1= $row['pid'];
 $qid1= $row['qid'];
 
 echo $row['question_link']."<br>";
 }
 
}

 $sql1= "SELECT pid, qid, aid, answer, points FROM answer_det WHERE pid=$pid1 AND qid=$qid1";

$result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);

if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result1->fetch_array()) {
  $answer= $row['answer'];
  $aid= $row['aid'];
 echo "<input type='radio' name='answers' value='".$answer."'/>".$answer."<br>";
 }
 
}

echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>";
```

Should i make another PHP page that saves the data into the database and shows the next question? or is there any function that can make that?

Answer (score 1):

depends on the case. If you want the user to stop on the way and maybe come back next time and finish it up, then DB is a good option. else you can use session to store their progress.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    //store answers in session
    $new = (!empty($_SESSION['session_name']))? $_SESSION['session_name'].'|'.$_POST['name'] : $_POST['name'];
    //split session into an array
    $_SESSION['session_name'] = $new;
}
else if(isset($_POST['clear'])){
    if(!empty($_SESSION['session_name'])){
        unset($_SESSION['session_name']);
        echo "cleared";
    }
    else
        echo "Nothing to Clear";
}
if(!empty($_SESSION['session_name'])){
    var_dump($_SESSION['session_name']);
}
//finish the procees here befor storing into database;
//use foreach to itterate btw arrays and match anwers
//$_SESSION['session_name'] = explode('|', $_SESSION['session_name']);
//answer table $answers = array('a','b','c','d','e');
/* foreach($_SESSION['session_name'] as $key => $ans){
     if($ans == $answer[$key]){
        //right procesesor
     }
     else{
        //wrong procesesor
     }
} */
//handle the right and wrong process get to total score the store in db


?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
   <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
  <input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear">
</form>
```

SIMPLE BASIC demo of how session can get the job done without querying the db each time.

Comment: i don't want that the users come back. They are gonna do the test just once and can not go back to the previous question

Comment: then use session to store their progress.

Comment: how do u mean use session? i'm not so good at session, but should i save everything in sessions and then save it in the DB at the end of the test?

Comment: do you want to save their final score? if no, u don't need a db whatsoever

Comment: Yes i want to save the answers in the database(i have radio buttons), cuz then i'm gonna show the result in a dashboard page